# Div top margin always equal

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to obtain always the same top margin, the code below gives me the always a bigger gap if i shorten the widht of the browser window.

```
<div style="float:left; width:100px; margin:5px; height:100px; background-color:blue"></div>
<div style="float:left; width:100px; margin:5px; height:70px; background-color:blue"></div>
<div style="float:left; width:100px; margin:5px; height:50px; background-color:blue"></div>
<div style="float:left; width:100px; margin:5px; height:30px; background-color:blue"></div>
```

How can I get the top margin alwas equal?

[image]

when I have the browser at full width the divs are displayed one next to another, if the browser size is reduced, I would like the gaps to be equal.

JsFiddle added:

https://jsfiddle.net/9b1ojqL3/

If you open the JsFiddle you see 4 squares with different hights, all in one line (4 columns), if you resize the browser so that you see only 2 columns you see exactly what you see in the image above, with a big gap between the 1st and 4th div.

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: instead of `margin:5px` try to use it in `%` values so that it get adjusted accordindly.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking sorry mate, can you provide some screen shots of what is happening and what should happen?

Comment: I think this will be difficult as you are going up against the height, even with `%` you will always be at a difference when specifying the height

Comment: @KawineshSK correct me if I'm wrong dude, but doesn't the real px value of a % change when you modify the browser width?

Comment: Are you trying to make this responsive, because your using fixed widths

Comment: I put your code in Jsfiddler and everything seems to have the same top-margin position, am I right? https://jsfiddle.net/rk9n1rh1/

Comment: the JSFiddle just has your code in there to show people what you've done already.

Comment: I suspect that OP is after something like the jquery masonary plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thanks everyone for the fast answers, I added a screenshot to better understand my issue

Comment: I agree with @MichaelCoxon so OP do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/85uuptvq/

Comment: Well, I think you can use media queries to manage your top margin, whenever you see a massive change in your margin add a media query for that position.

Comment: MichaelCoxon & @Sachin - Thank you for that, I did not know the js-masonry plugin. do you know if it is possible to integrate it into a wordpress plugin?

Comment: I don't think that there should be any issue with integrating with wordpress plugin as it just a js file which you can reference in your code but yes I am not much aware about wordpress plugin. ;)

Comment: Thanks again @Sachin :). I'll figure it out from here. How can I vote it as solved on your reply? Maby not possible as it is a comment? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `column-count` css property with `@media` queries:

> [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fo7t5z7f/2/)